# too many rows created in drupal view

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have modified the tpl used for the grid view to show 3 columns of content, my only issue that the code below creates unneeded divs for the view. I have a maximum of 9 items that should be output in 3 rows, 3 per column. What's the best way to modify the code below? to prevent the extra divs from being output.

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row_number => $columns): ?>
  <div>
    <?php foreach ($columns as $column_number => $item): ?>

        <?php print $item; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would drop that notation of foreach syntax (but I think that's pretty personal :-) )

You could use the modulo to check if you just had 3 columns (if I understood your question).

```
<?php

// I´m assuming that $column_number is a zero based index
// if thats not the case you should add a counter to keep track of column numbers or if it is in sequence but isn't zero based you could easily update the calculates based in your starting index

foreach ($rows as $row_number => $columns) {
    foreach ($columns as $column_number => $item) {
        if ($column_number == 0 || $column_number%3 == 0) {
            print '<div>';
        }
        print $item;
        if ($column_number == 2 || $column_number%3 == 2) {
            print '</div>';
        }
    }
    // prevent open div tags
    $total_columns = count($columns);
    if ($total_columns > 0 && ($total_columns < 3 || $total_columns%3 != 0)) {
        print('<div>');
    }
}
```

I've also dropped all those opening and closing tags of php for readability.

Comment: Thank you but this seems to throw an error that total_columns is undefined.

Comment: @Darren: I´m sorry that was a typo at the variable initialization. Fixed it